# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre los distintos diccionarios de la lengua de la RAE?

Tags: rae, dle

He visto que los diccionarios de la lengua publicados por la Real Academia Española tienen diferentes nombres: usual, manual, esencial, del estudiante.

En la página web de la RAE he encontrado que el **diccionario del estudiante** contiene menos voces (unas 40.000) y he visto que el **diccionario manual** incluye ilustraciones, mientras que el **usual** no.

¿Hay otras diferencias entre ellos?

Comment: por lo comun los diccionarios varian sus usos y definiciones para orientarlo a una area en especifico, creo que la unica manera de obtener un diciconario completo son las verciones enciclopedicas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efectivamente, la RAE edita diferentes ediciones de su diccionario, a saber:

- [Academia usual](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola). Conocido comúnmente como el DLE. Según cita la RAE: "es la obra lexicográfica académica por excelencia". Lleva 23 ediciones, siendo la primera de 1780, y se recoge en un único tomo. Desde 2001 cuenta con una edición [en línea](http://dle.rae.es/) para su consulta a través de la red, y desde 2016 se puede consultar y descargar desde una aplicación móvil. La edición de 1992, presente en el [NTLLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), contiene 1513 páginas, mientras que la última edición de 2014 contiene 2432 páginas, y según su prólogo "ofrece ahora 93111 entradas, con un total de 195439 acepciones".
- Academia manual. No parece ser una obra a la que la RAE le haya dado continuidad, dado que la última edición es de 1989 (se puede consultar también en el NTLLE), siendo la primera edición de 1927. Las diferencias con el usual, según el prólogo de la cuarta edición de 1989, "están en que el *Manual* suprime las palabras y acepciones anticuadas [...] a la vez que añade un considerable caudal de vocablos de uso común, neologismos de carácter técnico, voces del argot más en boga, etc. [...]. Todas estas voces y acepciones, aún no incluidas en el *Diccionario* general, aparecen en el *Manual* precedidas de un corchete ([). Este signo, en consecuencia, nos alerta sobre la realidad de su uso y nos recuerda su ausencia en la lengua oficial." Incluso recoge "usos incorrectos, barbarismos, etc." que señalan mediante un asterisco (*). Aparte de esto, también contiene algunas imágenes ilustrativas. Un ejemplo: la palabra *crupié* aparece marcada con un corchete en las cuatro ediciones del manual, pero no aparece ni siquiera hoy en el DLE (sí que lo hace *crupier*, que también empezó en el *Manual* y pasó al *Usual* en 1992). Como curiosidad, la última edición tiene 1666 páginas.
- [Diccionario esencial](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-esencial-de-la-lengua-espanola). Prosigue el espíritu del *Academia manual*, dado que en su página web comentan básicamente lo mismo que el citado prólogo del *Manual*: elimina los arcaísmos e incluye las novedades aprobadas para la siguiente edición del DLE (por no hablar de que en su prólogo lo confirman: "con su planteamiento y espíritu [del *Manual*] enlaza esta nueva obra"). Seguramente ahora con las revisiones anuales que pretende hacer la RAE al DLE, este diccionario deje de tener sentido. Solo tiene una edición, de 2006. Ojeando las definiciones se comprueba que estas han sido simplificadas, eliminando acepciones poco comunes, y aun así contiene 1684 páginas en su edición impresa. Se puede consultar [en línea](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/desen).
- [Diccionario del estudiante](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-del-estudiante). Dirigido a niños entre 12 y 18 años que aún están aprendiendo los entresijos de la lengua. "Las voces han sido cuidadosamente seleccionadas para recoger el vocabulario fundamental que en su trabajo debe manejar un estudiante de secundaria y bachillerato. Cada definición va acompañada de uno o más ejemplos basados en el uso real, que ilustran también las construcciones y combinaciones más características." Han aparecido hasta la fecha tres ediciones de este diccionario: la primera en 2001, la segunda en 2011 (que llevaba ya incorporadas las voces aprobadas para el DLE de 2014), y la más reciente de 2016, contiene 1584 páginas y más de 40000 voces, y cuenta con una aplicación móvil para su descarga, aunque no se puede consultar en línea.
- [Diccionario práctico del estudiante](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-practico-del-estudiante). Es una edición del diccionario del estudiante adaptada a los países hispanoamericanos, prescindiendo de muchas voces que solo se usan en el español europeo. Lleva dos ediciones (2007 y 2012) y contiene más de 30000 voces en sus 1544 páginas.